# How to browse other real PC with Redhat Linux 5 installed in VM?  

Tags: redhat, vmware-server, vmware-player

I need help on the following.

I have configured Virtual Network Manager to choose VMnet0 which is bridged to Physical adapter. I have installed Redhat linux 5.0. I am able to get connected to outside world (internet) but, I need to list access other real computers in LAN: How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Please check for the below URL for setting network adapter, also make sure if you are providing static ipaddress then it should be as per the local network ipaddress, that is if your local network ipaddress starts with 192.168.100 then your your lan ip should start with 192.168.100.

http://virt-manager.et.redhat.com/screenshots/networking.html